# How to pass function as parameter to another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the code like below:

```
if text == 'today':
    date1, date2 = dt.today_()
    result, data = ga.get_sessions_today_data(user_id, date1, date2)
    result, data, caption = get_final_caption(result, data, date1, date2, 'hour', 'sessions')
    handle_result(chat_id, result, data, caption)
elif text == 'yesterday':
    date1, date2 = dt.yesterday()
    result, data = ga.get_sessions_today_data(user_id, date1, date2)
    result, data, caption = get_final_caption(result, data, date1, end_date, 'hour', 'sessions')
    handle_result(chat_id, result, data, caption)
...
```

The code is repeated many-many times, just `dt.function()` and `ga.function()` are different. How could I optimize the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make a dictionary containing the functions for each possibility of `text`. Don't put parentheses after the functions, because you don't want to call them:

```
options = {"today": dt.today_, "yesterday": dt.yesterday} # etc
```

Then, you could do this to replace your existing code:

```
date1, date2 = options[text]() # Get the correct function and call it
result, data = ga.get_sessions_today_data(user_id, date1, date2)
result, data, caption = get_final_caption(result, data, date1, date2, 'hour', 'sessions')
handle_result(chat_id, result, data, caption)
```